# For Each loop Issue

Tags: vba, excel

I Have below vba code which works with vba "For Each Loop".
The problem is that I have used the below code in some other program, but in that the condition is same just I want to remove the loop thing in it.

The code should execute and stop after completing the task once. In short I want to remove the loop and do it in such a way where code runs without loop.

```
Set olNs = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myTasks = Fldr.Items

For Each olMail In myTasks
    If (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, ws.Range("E" & FinalRow), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        olMail.Display
    End If
Next olMail
```

Comment: Use `Exit For` just before `Next olMail` if you want torun it just once. If you want to exit after the `if` condition is met place it before `End if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Exit For` just before Next olMail if you want to run it just once. If you want to exit after the if condition is met place it before End if

Try this:

```
For Each olMail In myTasks
    If (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, ws.Range("E" & FinalRow), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
      olMail.Display
    Exit For
    End If
 Next olMail
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
For Each olMail In myTasks
If (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, ws.Range("E" & FinalRow), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
  olMail.Display
    End If
Next olMail
```

With

```
For Each olMail In myTasks
    If (InStr(1, olMail.Subject, ws.Range("E" & FinalRow), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        olMail.Display
        Exit For '// Exit the loop if the item is displayed.
    End If
Next olMail
```

Comment: This may not be exactly desired. I think OP wants to exit after the first match. myTasks(0) just tests it for that specific one.

Comment: @newguy the `For` loop will iterate over each item in the `myTasks` collection - which means the first 'match' or iteration will be the item at index 0. Therefore there is no need to use a loop at all, just access the first item in the collection directly.

Comment: @newguy nvm - I see what you mean, just re-read the question and updated.

Comment: Yes we don't know whether the 0th element will make the if condition true or not so we need the loop

Comment: @newguy When I first read the question, I thought the OP just didn't want to loop at all - hence the confusion.